# NullPointerException when unit testing Spray route

Tags: scala, spray

I am a Scala newbie, and I am moving my first steps with Spray.io. I have defined a bunch of routes that seem to work just fine when I manually run them through Curl. However, I do get a nasty NullPointerException when I try to unit test the 'GET /documents?q=' route using `spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest`.

Here is the route definition:

```
trait MyService extends HttpService {
import DocumentJsonProtocol._

val searchService: SearchService
val myRoute =
  path("documents") {
    post {
      entity(as[Document]) { doc =>
        detach() {
          val docId = searchService.indexDocument(doc)
          complete(201, s"document created: $docId")
        }
      }
    } ~
    get {
      parameter('q) { q =>
        detach() {
          val docs = searchService.matchingQuery(q)
          complete(docs)
        }
      }

    }
  } ~
  path("documents" / Segment ) { docId =>
    get {
      detach() {
        searchService.getDocument(docId) match {
          case Some(doc) => {
            complete(doc)
          }
          case None => {
            complete(404, s"Cannot find a document with id: $docId")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the failing test:

```
package example.com

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.mock._

import spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest
import spray.http._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._

import StatusCodes._

import com.example.services.SearchService
import com.example.data._
import DocumentJsonProtocol._

class MyServiceSpec extends Specification
                    with Specs2RouteTest 
                    with Mockito
                    with MyService {

  val searchService   = mock[SearchService]
  def actorRefFactory = system

  trait testDoc extends Scope {
    val docId   = "test-id"
    val testDoc =
      Document(Some(docId), "test-title", "test-author", "body", None)

    searchService.indexDocument(testDoc).returns(docId)
    searchService.matchingQuery("test-title").returns(List(testDoc))
  }

  "MyService" should {
      "allows to search documents by keyword" in new testDoc {
      Get("/documents?q=hello-test") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        Right(entity) === marshal(List(testDoc))
      }
    }
```

This fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] [04/07/2014 23:56:50.689] [io-composable-MyServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(io-composable-MyServiceSpec)] Error during processing of request HttpRequest(GET,http://ex
ample.com/documents?q=hello-test,List(),Empty,HTTP/1.1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:26)
        at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:25)
        at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonMarshaller$1.apply(SprayJsonSupport.scala:43)
        at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonMarshaller$1.apply(SprayJsonSupport.scala:42)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller$MarshallerDelegation$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:58)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller$MarshallerDelegation$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:58)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller$MarshallerDelegation$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Marshaller.scala:61)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller$MarshallerDelegation$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Marshaller.scala:60)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller$$anon$2.apply(Marshaller.scala:47)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.BasicToResponseMarshallers$$anon$1.apply(BasicToResponseMarshallers.scala:35)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.BasicToResponseMarshallers$$anon$1.apply(BasicToResponseMarshallers.scala:22)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:69)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Marshaller.scala:69)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller$$anon$3.apply(Marshaller.scala:81)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable$$anon$6.marshal(Marshaller.scala:141)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable$$anon$7.apply(Marshaller.scala:145)
        at spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable$$anon$7.apply(Marshaller.scala:144)
        at spray.routing.RequestContext.complete(RequestContext.scala:235)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I could see after reading your code is that you mock `matchingQuery` function with **"test-title"** argument and make request with **"hello-test"** query parameter which leads mock to return null.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for spotting that! I thought that the cause of the error was some obscure JSON serialisation issue, instead is just the mock object! However, I would have expected a more informative error message instead of a NullPointerException